# ImportError for some but not all classes in package installed from TestPyPI

Tags: python, import, pypi

I am trying to publish a package on PyPI. First, I [uploaded it to TestPyPI](https://test.pypi.org/project/neuralpp/) then installed it on a fresh Conda environment with

```
python3 -m pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple/ neuralpp
```

However I am unable to import some classes from the package. The minimal example below illustrates this:

```python
# main.py
from neuralpp.inference.graphical_model.representation.table.pytorch_log_table import PyTorchLogTable

from neuralpp.inference.graphical_model.representation.factor import PyTorchTableFactor
```

When I run `python main.py`, the first import (`PyTorchLogTable`) works, but not the second (`PyTorchTableFactor`). See the error message at the end of the question.

I checked the package files (within the Conda environment) and the required files are present. This also works fine in the original project I uploaded.

Because the error message mentions `__init__.py`, I've added `__all__ = ['PyTorchTableFactor']` to it, even though I know the use of `__all__` is not mandatory. However, this has not changed anything. Besides, the `__init__.py` for `PyTorchLogTable` is also empty and that is imported correctly, further confirming that this is not the issue.

What is wrong here, and how can I fix it?

Error message:

```
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from neuralpp.inference.graphical_model.representation.factor import PyTorchTableFactor
ImportError: cannot import name 'PyTorchTableFactor' from 'neuralpp.inference.graphical_model.representation.factor' (/Users/rodrigobraz/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/neuralpp/inference/graphical_model/representation/factor/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Since `PyTorchTableFactor` is defined in https://github.com/rodrigodesalvobraz/neuralpp/blob/main/neuralpp/inference/graphical_model/representation/factor/pytorch_table_factor.py, I think your import should be `    from neuralpp.inference.graphical_model.representation.factor.pytorch_table_factor import PyTorchTableFactor`  *as your structure is currently defined*.

Comment: Thanks, yes. I copied that from the original project but it turns out that was broken there too and I hadn't realized it!